# Clock Time loss on windows server 2008 r2 upto 10 sec per min

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

The windows Enterprise server has been loosing time of up to 10 sec per min.

- I am running MSSQL on the server and there are jobs that need to execute at specific  time.
- If i leave the machine on over night starting at 2100-HRS the next
  morning at 0900-hrs it will be reading 0200-hrs.

I have been looking for a solution for almost a week and a half now and have gone through many sites with no solution. I have now run out options or ideas.

If i any suggestions require checking the event log or any troubleshooting i would like a step by step explanation as i am not really good in windows.

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the Clock Battery?

Comment: Yes I have Jack, but CMOS battery usually applies when your machine is off. So I think it was a wast of time :) It did not work.

Comment: Are you sure it is simply running slow, as opposed to intermittently stopping or being reset?

Comment: fixer1234 its  not being reset because when on it i can see the drug, comparing it with my current watch time. I dont know if I am clear. Did I answer your question?